# Creating action in view from user model action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the User model I have it setup for user to remove themselves from email notifications. How do I call the code in the view so user can click on a link to remove notifications? When link is created it should update the column `no_email` to a value such as `1`.

I know this is a noob question but I have typically setup routes and then placed the action in the view. I didn't think that should be necessary for this.

```
def mailboxer_email(object)
    if self.no_email
    email
  else
    nil
  end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<div class="forms">
<%= f.check_box :no_email, :value => 1 %>
<%= f.submit 'Unsubscribe from notifications' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

In the user model add `no_email` to the attr_accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The action you would call would be "users#update", passing a parameter of "user[no_email]=1" in the normal railsy way of doing things.

I would normally do an ajaxy form for this sort of thing.

```
<%= remote_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :no_email, :onchange => "$(this).closest('form').submit();" %>
<% end %>
```